# Getting an error when running the app in iPhone device in React Native

Tags: react-native

please help me , I'm stuck an error, 
when running the app in ios simulator it's working fine, but when i was run it in iphone device, getting an error , Please found attached screen shot for the same.

React-Native Version: 0.50.3

Mac OS Version: 11.12.6

[image]